# How to upload a file without refreshing page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload files in server folder but while uploading i dont want to refresh aspx page. 
I mean to say i dont want refresh page while i click on upload button.
So how can i do??

Comment: Have you tried looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: @dtryon: I have tried it but not working.

Comment: What or how doesn't it work? We can't read your mind. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: You mean to say you dont understand my que??

Comment: [You haven't shown what you've tried and you haven't told us what isn't working](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: @J.Steen: Mr. Steen I have tried that link. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/), it does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: PHP is just used to demo the function. It's not actually contained in the plugin.

Comment: The examples use php, however you can use it to post files to any server. I use it with ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: You mean you dont need PHP files while your development which are associated with your link.